# GoogleApiClient not working Android

Tags: android, sdk, google-drive-android-api

I added the Drive API to my project but still can't get GoogleApiClient.
Any solutions ?

Thanks

[image: Google Api]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add the play services library.